# Force the strategy to enter a trade only at the close of the candle

Tags: pine-script

how to force the strategy to enter a trade only at the close of the candle or in the last 5 seconds before the end of the candle in real trading? What condition to add or what to do?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
// This source code is subject to the terms of the Mozilla Public License 2.0 at https://mozilla.org/MPL/2.0/
// © adolgov

//@version=4
strategy("My Strategy", overlay=true, margin_long=100, margin_short=100, calc_on_every_tick=true)

// some random entry
if barstate.islast and strategy.position_size==0 and strategy.closedtrades == 0
    strategy.entry("My Long Entry Id", strategy.long)

if time_close - timenow <= 5*1000
    strategy.close_all()
```